# How to extract the data on the right-hand side of the arrows in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, replace, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to extract the values after the arrows. If there is no arrow, then the expected output will be the value in the cell. I know that this can be done by using few functions (`REPLACE` or `SUBSTITUTE`) in another column, but I want to make this happen inside the `QUERY` function or wrap the `QUERY`function inside some functions so that I'm not require to have extra column to get the values after the arrow (if available). I'm not sure whether this can be achieved.

I tried to wrap the `QUERY` function inside a `REPLACE` function but this doesn't work.

The value in column F is the expected output that I want. Appreciate for any feedback or suggestion, thank you!

Comment: Use `SPLIT()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=INDEX(
   REGEXEXTRACT(
     QUERY(
       IMPORTHTML(
       "https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NYSE/NKE/price-target/", "table", 2), 
     "Select Col5 where Col5 is not null and Col1 > date 
     '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(B2), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0), 
   "\$?[0-9.]+$")
)
```

Note that the output will be strings (text). To convert to number, change

```
"\$?[0-9.]+$")
```

to

```
"\$?[0-9.]+$")+0
```

and format the output column as 'valuta'.

[image: Example]